# How can I use an argument in an R function as both text and expression?

Tags: r

Here's my example function. As a hack, I'm passing the column name twice, once as a variable and again as the name of the variable. I'd like to just pass it once, unquoted.

```
split_by_quartile <- function(some_tibble, col_name_fn, col_name_text){
  # get the upper quartile of the value
      this_threshold <- some_tibble %>% summarize(this_q = quantile({{col_name_fn}}, 0.75)) %>% pull(this_q) %>% unique
  # filter using that value and create a label
        some_tibble_upper_bit <- some_tibble %>% 
      filter({{col_name_fn}} > this_threshold) %>% # filter using that value
      mutate(set = paste0(col_name_text, ">", round(this_threshold, 1), ", n=", label_comma()(n()))) 
}
```

and here's how I'm using the function and output

```
figure1_data <- bind_rows(
split_by_quartile(as_tibble(mtcars), col_name = disp, col_name_text="disp"),
split_by_quartile(as_tibble(mtcars), col_name = hp, col_name_text="hp")
)

ggplot(figure1_data, aes(y=set, x=mpg)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

This is the most promising R page: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html. It shows how use glue syntax in conjunction with := to use the names of variables in the output variable name, but not in the output value.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the symbol, you'll need to capture explicitly rather than passing it through with `{{}}`. Try this

```
split_by_quartile <- function(some_tibble, col_name_fn){
  col_name_sym <- rlang::ensym(col_name_fn)
  # get the upper quartile of the value
  this_threshold <- some_tibble %>% summarize(this_q = quantile(!!col_name_sym, 0.75)) %>% pull(this_q) %>% unique
  # filter using that value and create a label
  some_tibble_upper_bit <- some_tibble %>% 
    filter(!!col_name_sym > this_threshold) %>% # filter using that value
    mutate(set = paste0(rlang::as_label(col_name_sym), ">", round(this_threshold, 1), ", n=", scales::label_comma()(n()))) 
}
```

Notice how we capture the symbol here with `rlang::ensym`. We can then expand it with `!!` or turn it into a string with `rlang::as_label()`

Comment: Should be `rlang::as_label(col_name_sym)` instead of `rlang::as_label(col_name_expr)`. (;

Comment: @stefan Thanks. Had a last minute variable change. It's now been corrected

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!